# Dynamically created checkbox won't work on mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, checkbox, mobile-safari

Please check this fiddle out:

http://jsfiddle.net/1f79fosh/

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.checkbox = div.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
div.checkbox.type = "checkbox";
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Now try it on a desktop browser. It will work. But if you try it on mobile safari, when you click it, it will open tweeter (?!) and also will not change status (check symbol not shown).

What I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have social icons on your page, including tweeter? Is it possible to share that part of your html ?

Comment: @lvigiani Thanks for the fiddle. I opened the fiddle in mobile safari. It seems to be working on my test phone: Iphone 4s IOS 7.1

Comment: I'm ios 8.4 on iPad here...

Comment: @Lciggiani OK. I will try it on my ipad too. give me 2 mins.

Comment: it works fine on my ipad IOS 8.4 . I know "works-for-me" is not a good answer but you might be barking at the wrong tree. =] Good luck

Comment: did you open this http://jsfiddle.net/1f79fosh/ in mobile safari and it worked??

Comment: yes. That's what I did and said. That's why I am telling you that the problem might be actually something else and not the thing that you think what problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test in Safari easily, but try:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var inp = document.createElement("input");
inp.type = "checkbox";
div.appendChild(inp);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Explanation: In your original code, in the second line, your reference to the newly-forged checkbox control was actually assigned to a property of the divider (div) element. This may have introduced an error in Safari.

Comment: I have just updated my answer to explain, @lviggiani.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Neither by inserting the checkbox directly in the html: http://jsfiddle.net/1f79fosh/5/

Comment: Hmm. Well. I've just tried your jsfiddle on a couple of different versions of desktop Safari via browserstack.com. And it works. My suspicion is that the code snippet that you provided is not the true source of the error. I'm out of other ideas as this juncture, sorry mate.

Comment: You should open my link (not my code) into jsfiddle with a REAL iPad/iPhone with MOBILE safari... simulators seems to work fine

Comment: Yes, iOS8 emulator works just fine. I'm afraid I don't currently have access to a real iOS device. Hopefully someone else will be able to help. Good luck!